# IndexOutOfRangeException With Array

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I am attempting to iterate my array of points, but I am getting the below error:

> Un unhandled exception of Type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occured

This is my syntax -- and i have a comment above the line that is throwing the error

How should this syntax be written so I can retrieve i - 1 position?

```
private void btnMakeCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point[] pts = new Point[] { new Point { X = -100, Y = 0 }, new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.Count(); i++)
    {
        float X1value = pts[i].X;
        //The below line throws the error
        float X2value = pts[i-1].X;
        MessageBox.Show("X1 Is: " + Convert.ToString(pts[i].X) + "Environment.NewLine" + "X2 Is: " + Convert.ToString(pts[i-1].X));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with `i = 1`, or use `i` and `i - 1` and finish one early.

Comment: @Winnie - if I change my loop to be i < pts.Count() - 1 I still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are trying to point to a value before the first entry, try including a check to see that it is not the (very first entry-1) you are pointing at.

Something like:

```
private void btnMakeCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point[] pts = new Point[] { new Point { X = -100, Y = 0 }, new Point { X = 0, Y = 0 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < pts.Count(); i++)
    {
        float X1value = pts[i].X;
        //The below line throws the error (see fix)
        if (i != 0)
            float X2value = pts[i-1].X;
            MessageBox.Show("X1 Is: " + Convert.ToString(pts[i].X) + "Environment.NewLine" + "X2 Is: " + Convert.ToString(pts[i-1].X));
        else
          continue;
    }
}
```

I like to refer to these little checks as "sanity checks" i don't know if that is colloquially accepted.